# ssh2_exec process failing before completion PHP Bash

Tags: php, bash, wget, ssh2-exec

I've got a PHP script that executes a bash script on a remote server which fires a number of processes.

```
 <?php   
 $connection = ssh2_connect('address1.com', 22);
 ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');

 $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/root/incoming/process.sh');
 ?>
```

The bash script process.sh works fine when executed locally on the remote server, no issues.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 wget -O /root/incoming/myfile.mp3 http://address2.com/myfile.mp3;

 lame --decode /root/incoming/myfile.mp3 - | /usr/settings/stereo_tool_cmd_64 - - -s /usr/settings/setting.sts | lame -b 128 - /var/www/processed/myfile.mp3
```

But when I try to execute it remotely using the PHP script it bombs out at various stages of the first process (wget). It doesn't even complete the wget download, stopping at random stages of the transfer.

Is this an issue with PHP ssh2_exec?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Found it after much hunting..

My PHP script doesn't require any feedback from the shell script, I just needed to start it and forget about it.

What solved my problem was the following :

```
 $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/root/incoming/process.sh &> /dev/null &");
```

Hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Add `set_time_limit ( 0 );` to the beginning of the script. PHP usually defaults to timing out after 30 seconds.

Comment: Nope that hasn't changed anything. Still bombing. I should add that it is bombing out after about 2 seconds.

Comment: It's like the second set (lame) is trying to start before wget has finished. I've tried adding sleep 10 & wait  before the lame process but nothing is making any difference

Comment: @Grant Could it be that the `;` at the end of `wget` line somehow triggers background execution of that command in your shell? Does that script behave the same when you launch it interactively by yourself?

Comment: @AntonSamsonov It runs perfectly locally with or without the ; - remotely nothing seems to execute correctly with or without the ; - Remotely, If I remove the second command leaving only the wget it sometimes works downloading the complete file and sometimes it only grabs a few mb of the file then stops. Just leaving the lame command only remotely doesn't work at all.

Comment: I should add both servers have ssh2 installed and they are both key paired. Also the bash script has the correct permissions so it's not a security issue.

Comment: Try adding `stream_set_blocking ($stream, true);`. It's possible you are getting something back from the wget command and it is closing out assuming that you have gotten the full response.

Comment: @BA_Webimax tried that, no difference. This is so weird. Just can't figure out why this isn't working!